# Showing incomplete name definition in a flex file naevigationg on git bash

Tags: flexbox, compiler-errors, git-bash

%option noyywrap

%{

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

ofstream yyoutlog; //output filestream for log file

string loglist = ""; //list of tokens along with line numbers

// define necessary c++ variables and functions here (if any)
int lines=1; //to keep track of line numbers

%}

/* Regular Definitions */

delim [ \t\n]

/* write regular expressions for whitespace and newline */
ws

newline

letter [a-zA-Z]
digit [0-9]

/* write regular expressions for id, float and integers */

id
%%

{ws} { /* ignore whitespace */ }

{newline} {

```
    /* do necessary bookkeeping (line number tracking etc.) */
}
```

{id} {
loglist="Line no "+to_string(lines)+": Token  Lexeme "+yytext+" found"+"\n"+"\n";
yyoutlog<<loglist;
}

if {
loglist="Line no "+to_string(lines)+": Token  Lexeme "+yytext+" found"+"\n"+"\n";
yyoutlog<<loglist;
}

range {
loglist="Line no "+to_string(lines)+": Token  Lexeme "+yytext+" found"+"\n"+"\n";
yyoutlog<<loglist;
}

"+"|"-" { /* to match two same operators use | */
loglist="Line no "+to_string(lines)+": Token  Lexeme "+yytext+" found"+"\n"+"\n";
yyoutlog<<loglist;
}

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

```
if(argc != 2) //check if file name is given
{
    cout<<"Please input file name"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r"); //the file to be read must be assigned to yyin

yyoutlog.open("my_log.txt", ios::trunc); // remember to rename the log file as mentioned in the spec

if(yyin == NULL) // file does not exist
{
    // print error message and exit
}

yylex(); // start reading the input file in a loop

//print total number of lines found in the input file

yyoutlog.close(); // close the log file

fclose(yyin); // close the input file
```

}

showing Incomplete name definition in ws, newline,id and undefined definition in {ws},{newline},{id}